# Script#: Determine if imported type is null

Tags: script#

I'm writing code that calls an external JavaScript library Foo but only if Foo is defined.  The equivalent JavaScript code should looks something like this:

```
if (typeof(Foo) != "undefined") {
  Foo.bar();
}
```

I've tried the following in Script#:

- **if (!Script.IsNullOrDefined(Foo)):** My project requires aacorlib and cannot use sscorlib, where IsNullOrDefined is defined.
- **if (typeof(Foo).ToString() != "undefined"):** Results in Foo.toString() !== 'undefined' which will fail because Foo is undefined.
- **if ((string)Type.InvokeMethod(null, "typeof", "Foo") != "undefined"):** Compile error "The name of a global method must be a valid identifier", referring to "typeof".
- **if (Type.IsClass(typeof(Foo))):**Fails at runtime with "Foo undefined" error.
- **if (typeof(Foo) != null):**Emits "if(Foo!= null)" which throws "Foo undefined" error.

What should the Script# code look like to generate this JavaScript code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Script.Literal("if (typeof(Foo) != \"undefined\") { Foo.bar(); }");
```